# How to create user in AD using FIM 2010 Sync Service Only?

Tags: microsoft-forefront, microsoft-forefront-2010

I am new to FIM 2010 R2(MIM 2016). I want to create user in AD from my DB. I have DB that contains student information and based on that I want to create user in AD.

I want to perform this action using only FIM Sync Service only.

How Can I get user from DB to FIM ? Later FIM to AD ?

Any help would be highly appreciable.

Comment: You should read the tutorial on Microsft webpages. It is a complex process.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I know that It is complex process but as I am new I am bit confuse that from where I do have to start. Any help in that direction also helpful to me. I know that I have to understand many terminology but I need starting point.